# Android client socket is connecting but server socket is not accepting?

Tags: android, sockets, client-server, client

I am trying to connect two android devices via wifi and send some data. On client side socket is showing connected but server is not moving ahead of accept. I am not even sure how that's possible. Below is my server and client code.I have connected both the devices using wifi hotspot running on one of the device.

Server Side:

```
    try
    {
          ServerSocket servsock = new ServerSocket(4149);

              Log.d("VR","Waiting");
                text.setText("waiting"); //code reaching upto here



              Socket sock = servsock.accept();
              //System.out.println("Accepted connection11 : " + sock);
              text.setText("this is acc"+servsock); 
              //Log.d("VR","Accepted");
                text.setText("accepted");


           // receive file
                byte [] mybytearray  = new byte [filesize];
                InputStream is = sock.getInputStream();
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/WebOffice.jpg"); // destination path and name of file
                BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
                bytesRead = is.read(mybytearray,0,mybytearray.length);
                current = bytesRead;


                do {
                   bytesRead =
                      is.read(mybytearray, current, (mybytearray.length-current));
                   if(bytesRead >= 0) current += bytesRead;
                } while(bytesRead > -1);

                bos.write(mybytearray, 0 , current);
                bos.flush();

                long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
                System.out.println(end-start);
                bos.close();



              sock.close();


              Log.d("VR","Socket closed");

                  Log.d("VR","image should be loaded by now");
                    text.setText("image should be loaded by now");


                Intent i  = new Intent(this,ImageDisplay.class);
                startActivity(i);








    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
```

Client Side:

try {

```
                    ThreadPolicy tp = ThreadPolicy.LAX;
                    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(tp);
                    ip = et.getText().toString();
                    sock = new Socket("192.168.43.182",4149); 

                    status.setText("connecting");
                    status.setText("connected"+sock);

                    System.out.println("Connecting...");

                     // sendfile
                          File myFile = new File (selectedImagePath); 
                          byte [] mybytearray  = new byte [(int)myFile.length()];
                          FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(myFile);
                          BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
                          bis.read(mybytearray,0,mybytearray.length);
                          OutputStream os = sock.getOutputStream();
                          System.out.println("Sending...");
                          os.write(mybytearray,0,mybytearray.length);
                          os.flush();

                        sock.close();

                        //Intent i  = new Intent(Sender.this,ImageReceive.class);
                        //startActivity(i);
                } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your own comment says that the code gets to the line after the accept, so I don't know what you're asking about. However your copy loops should all look like this:

```
while ((count = in.read(buffer)) >= 0)
{
  out.write(buffer, 0, count);
}
```

There's no reason to introduce delay and waste memory by reading all the input into a huge buffer, or a ByteArrayInputStream, before writing any output. 'buffer' can be any reasonable size, e.g. 2k.

Comment: Hii, thanks for replying..that was a typing error..server is not accepting connections for some reason i can't figure it out why. I would also like to add that when same code is ran on a pc as java code it works..in android i have added all the permissions and the code is running within an activity..there is no threading whatsoever.

Comment: @nitinsh99 If it's 'not accepting connections' how does it get to the line after the `accept()` call?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to resolve the issue..there was no server IP address to begin with..for some reason android 4.2 is not binding socket to device ip address...when i tried to ran the same code on gingerbread it worked..I came to the conclusion that jelly bean doesn't support socket programming anymore..may be google is forcing us to use wifidirect api's to attain adhoc networking rather then server client programming..